# Creating a workflow to populate column when something in another column is selected

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have one table that has job role, benefit grade and benefit points in it.
In another table i have a list of employees and if they are active.
In the employees table i would like to add in the job role and when i do that i want another column to populate with the benefit point assigned to that job role.
E.g add in manager and another column populates with amount of benefit points for a manager

how can this be done? is it with a workflow or another way?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!